# How to Download Document from Sharepoint Librarly and display in ASP.NET programatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, download, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have created a document library with name `"ARTICLES"` in SHAREPOINT which stores documents. Now, I want to display the documents in Repeater and clicking on row it must display the document. And also all documents must be Downloaded in Application folder.

```
The application is pure asp.net application using c# and not a webpart or other.
```

Help appreciated!
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not suit your application (and it isn't exactly what you asked for), there is a much easier way of achieving what you described (suited for intranet applications where Windows Authentication is used).

It involves two parts:

1. In your web application add a `IFRAME` that points to your SharePoint library (using the default SharePoint web interface).
2. [optional] Add a custom master page to this library so that you can hide menus etc.

For many applications this solution is sufficient and saves you lot of trouble of coding the integration (and retesting it with every SharePoint update) decoupling your application from SharePoint. It also makes sure that the end user can use all SharePoint functionality such as uploading the changes directly from Word etc.